# Cryptsetup performance

Tags: linux, performance, benchmarking

I am newbie to Linux Cryptsetup. I have used Phoronix test suite to execute the benchmark on ARM & RISCV64 platform. Now, I am seeing some degradation in one of the platform.
I went through multiple weblinks & videos but did not get proper way.
Could someone help with approach for finding reason of degradation?

Thanks